# How can I get my Perl regex to match only if $1 < $2?

Tags: regex, perl

The part that I can't quite get to work is the conditional as it's always failing:

```
use Test::More tests => 2;

my $regex = qr/(\d+),(\d+)
               (?(?{\g1<\g2})(*FAIL))
              /x ;

  like( "(23,36)", $regex, 'should match'     );
unlike( "(36,23)", $regex, 'should not match' );
```

#### Output

```
not ok 1 - should match
#   Failed test 'should match'
#   at - line 7.
#                   '(23,36)'
#     doesn't match '(?^x:(\d+),(\d+)
#                    (?(?{\g1<\g2})(*FAIL))
#                   )'
ok 2 - should not match
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code needs the following fixes:

- Use the `$1` and `$2` variables in the experimental [`(?{ })`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic%3a-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression) code block.
- Need to invert your test to match what you want to fail.
- You need to prevent backtracking where if the code block indicates a failure, you don't want it to match a substring that will pass, such as 6 is less then 23 in the second test.  There are two methods to prevent this:

  - Add word boundaries so the regex can't match a partial number.
  - Use the [`(*SKIP)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) control verb to prevent backtracking explicitly.

The code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 2;

my $regex = qr/(\d+),(\d+)
               (?(?{$1 > $2})(*SKIP)(*FAIL))
              /x ;

  like( "(23,36)", $regex, 'should match'     );
unlike( "(36,23)", $regex, 'should not match' );
```

Outputs:

```
1..2
ok 1 - should match
ok 2 - should not match
```

Comment: Yes I ***do*** need to invert my test, not sure how I missed that :(

Comment: @Miller Couldn't you use `my $regex = qr/\b(\d+),(\d+)\b(??{$1 > $2})/;` here?

Comment: (I wonder why `(?{})` is still considered "experimental" =^_^=)

Comment: I couldn't find any place in the documentation where it mentions that `$1` should be used instead of `\g1` inside code blocks.

Comment: @hwnd That would work technically, but almost by accident.  When that evaluates to true, it tries to match the number 1 within the string.  But because the regex ends in \d\b, it's impossible for there to be a trailing 1.  When the condition fails, it tries to match the empty string and passes.  So it *"works"*, but by accident.  And within other context might easily fail.

Comment: @Zaid I can't find it in the docs either, however it's logical since it's perl code and not regex markup.  Also, if under `use strict`, it will report `Bareword "g1" not allowed while "strict subs"`, so obviously worth trying the RHS form.

Answer (score 3):

Although Miller's solution does exactly what you requested - implement the check entirely within the regular expression match - I would be remiss if I didn't suggest a saner solution :-) Don't do this with a regular expression alone!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 2;

sub match {
    my $str = shift;

    if ($str =~ m/ (\d+) , (\d+) /x) {
        return $1 < $2;
    }

    return;
}

ok(match("(23,36)"), 'should match');
ok(!match("(36,23)"), 'should not match');
```

This is much clearer, simpler, and probably faster!

```
1..2
ok 1 - should match
ok 2 - should not match
```

Comment: If this was just a case of a simple match, I totally agree with you. In my actual problem I was performing a conditional substitution with `s///`, where it would be a bit more messy to test for `$1 < $2` outside the regex. +1 for the sanity check.

Comment: Understood - but I still think I would do a separate match, check, then substitution even in that case :-) Might be worth running two the solutions through [Dumbbench](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dumbbench/). I have a sneaking suspicion that the experimental `?{}` code block is slow. Of course only if performance is important... but if it's not I would default to the clearer more self-documenting solution.

Comment: Good advice, but my Regex is being using to find/replace in VsCode, where I can ONLY use regular expressions. (Help.)