# Match the nth longest possible string in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, pattern-matching

The pattern matching quantifiers of a Perl regular expression are "greedy" (they match the longest possible string). To force the match to be "ungreedy", a ? can be appended to the pattern quantifier (*, +).

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$string="111s11111s";

#-- greedy match
$string =~ /^(.*)s/;
print "$1\n"; # prints 111s11111

#-- ungreedy match
$string =~ /^(.*?)s/;
print "$1\n"; # prints 111
```

But how one can find the second, third and .. possible string match in Perl? Make a simple example of yours --if need a better one.

Comment: Bad example. Those are the only two possible matches!

Comment: @ikegami That's exactly why I said "Make a simple example of yours --if need a better one.".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Utilize a [conditional expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Conditional-expressions), a [code expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic%3a-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression), and [backtracking control verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backtracking-control-verbs).

```
my $skips = 1;
$string =~ /^(.*)s(?(?{$skips-- > 0})(*FAIL))/;
```

The above will use greedy matching, but will cause the largest match to intentionally fail.  If you wanted the 3rd largest, you could just set the number of skips to 2.

Demonstrated below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "111s11111s11111s";

$string =~ /^(.*)s/;
print "Greedy match     - $1\n";

$string =~ /^(.*?)s/;
print "Ungreedy match   - $1\n";

my $skips = 1;
$string =~ /^(.*)s(?(?{$skips-- > 0})(*FAIL))/;
print "2nd Greedy match - $1\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Greedy match     - 111s11111s11111
Ungreedy match   - 111
2nd Greedy match - 111s11111
```

When using such advanced features, it is important to have a full understanding of regular expressions to predict the results. This particular case works because the regex is fixed on one end with `^`. That means that we know that each subsequent match is also one shorter than the previous. However, if both ends could shift, we could not necessarily predict order.

If that were the case, then you find them all, and then you sort them:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "111s11111s";

my @seqs;
$string =~ /^(.*)s(?{push @seqs, $1})(*FAIL)/;

my @sorted = sort {length $b <=> length $a} @seqs;

use Data::Dump;
dd @sorted;
```

Outputs:

```
("111s11111s11111", "111s11111", 111)
```

#### Note for Perl versions prior to `v5.18`

Perl `v5.18` introduced a change, [`/(?{})/` and `/(??{})`/ have been heavily reworked](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#/%28?%7B%7D%29/_and_/%28??%7B%7D%29/_have_been_heavily_reworked), that enabled the scope of lexical variables to work properly in code expressions as utilized above. Before then, the above code would result in the following errors, as demonstrated in [this subroutine version run under v5.16.2](http://ideone.com/8mIHAQ):

```
Variable "$skips" will not stay shared at (re_eval 1) line 1.
Variable "@seqs" will not stay shared at (re_eval 2) line 1.
```

The fix for older implementations of RE code expressions is to declare the variables with [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html), and for further good coding practices, to [`localize`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) them when initialized. This is demonstrated in this [modified subroutine version run under v5.16.2](http://ideone.com/7pZDDi), or as put below:

```
local our @seqs;
$string =~ /^(.*)s(?{push @seqs, $1})(*FAIL)/;
```

Comment: `my @seqs;` needs to be `local our @seqs;` if used in a sub.

Comment: @ikegami I did a little research into your warning, and have adjusted my answer.  It appears they fixed that issue with 5.18, but I was able to confirm that you were right for older versions using http://ideone.com/.  Please let me know if I'm missing anything else.

Comment: @AmalMurali I do not agree with your edit, but don't disagree enough to  revert.  Yes, those three instances were not strict interpretation of code, but there are allowances for stylistic variations in this system.

Comment: Re "It appears they fixed that issue with 5.18", oh nice!

Comment: @Miller: Actually, no. This has been discussed many times before (see [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176902/220538), [3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/1438393)). Using inline code formatting for emphasis has always been frowned upon; that's what bold and italics are there for.

Comment: @AmalMurali Stop it. You're being rude. I showed you courtesy enough to not revert your original edit, but to instead engage you in conversation.  But instead of showing me similar respect, you've gone ahead and asserted your opinion again in my creative content.  Your Link 1 is referring to suggested edits, not OP creative content.  The primary answer says that "*computer things*" should probably count, and the link 3 says "*don't know if it's possible to make a definitive list*".  I agree that my usage is an edge case even in my own estimation, but you're being rude to not talk first.

Answer (score 3):

Start by getting all possible matches.

```
my $string = "111s1111s11111s";
local our @matches;
$string =~ /^(.*)s(?{ push @matches, $1 })(?!)/;
```

This finds

```
111s1111s11111
111s1111
111
```

Then, it's just a matter of finding out which one is the second longuest and filtering out the others.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );

my $target_length = ( sort { $b <=> $a } uniq map length, @matches )[1];

@matches = uniq grep { length($_) == $target_length } @matches
   if $target_length;
```

Comment: I've only ever bothered using code expressions [one other time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23905882/1733163), so don't have a lot of experience.  Why `local our`?  Is that just habit in case you want to localize the changes to variables inside the code expression in case of backtracking as described in [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic%3a-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression)?

Comment: @Miller, Because the pattern is compiled a compile-time, so the closure happens at compile-time, so `sub foo { my @matches; ... }` will place in the wrong variable after the first call ("won't stay shared").

Comment: Any contribution on [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519747/replacing-string-2-to-sqrt-string-in-perl) will be greatly appreciated. There is only one buggy answer so far.