# Replacing ( string ) ^ 2 to sqrt ( string ) in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace, pattern-matching

A given string (called `$bbb`!) contains many operands and operators. I want to replace every occurrence of
`muth ( math ) ^ 2 mith` to `muth sqrt( math ) mith`. (whitespace can be more than just one).

**EDIT:**
Assume that, in the entire expression, there is only either one `(simple linear expression) ^ 2` or none --if it makes it easier.

**Inclusive Example:**

`1.2 * ( 4.7 * a * ( b - 0.02 ) ^ 2 * ( b - 0.02 + 1 ) / ( b -  0.0430 ) )`

should be changed to:

`1.2 * ( 4.7 * a * sqrt( b - 0.02 ) * ( c - 0.02 + 1 ) / ( d -  0.0430 ) )`

Comment: Is "muth" "math" and "mith" supposed to be some arbitrary strings? Or are they fixed strings?

Comment: @user3761870, To matched balanced parens, you'll need a recursive pattern. Search [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for "recursive". Show your work.

Comment: It's not clear what language your expressions are in, but generally I would expect x ^ 2 to be different to sqrt(x).  i.e. x ^ 2 = x * x, and x ^ 0.5 = sqrt(x).

Comment: @IanCook I know it's odd. In that case, the problem would be just replacing `^` with `**`.

Answer (score 0):

Well... weird problem...

Try it with this a bit *advanced* expression

```
(?<math>\((?:[^()]+|(?&math))*\))\s*\^\s*2
```

Hopefully the graphic illustrates what's going on

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JTJHrsv4hlK05nss)

The replacement string must  than be `sqrt $1`

The command in perl would look like

```
$bbb =~ s/(?<math>\((?:[^()]+|(?&math))*\))\s*\^\s*2/sqrt $1/
```

A running example can be found here: http://regex101.com/r/qU8dV0/3

---

**some words on what the heck, this is**

the main structure here is `anything\s*\^\s*2`, it's matching anything followed by `^2`

- `(?<math>...)` builds a pattern named *`math`*
- `\(...\)` the pattern *`math`* must begin with an opening parenthesis and end with a closing one
- **within the parenthesisses:**

  - `[^()]+` anything except parenthesisses is allowed or
  - `(?&math)` another in parenthesis wrapped term with the already defined structure, is allowed, so the outer pattern *`math`* is recursively repeated

Comment: muth, math and mith were just names. They are some arbitrary expressions (or strings). Let me know if I'm missing anything --I'm new to Perl. This `$bbb =~ (?<muth>.*)(?<math>\((?:[^()]+|(?&math))*\))\s*\^\s*2(?<mith>.*)` didn't work.

Comment: Please be more explicit, how I can incorporate it with `$bbb`. Thanks @bukfixart

Comment: in perl I'm not better, maybe this will help


`$bbb =~ s/(?<muth>.*)(?<math>\((?:[^()]+|(?&math))*\))\s*\^\s*2(?<mith>.*)/\1sqrt \2\3/`

Comment: `\1 better written as $1 at -e line 1.
\2 better written as $2 at -e line 1.
\3 better written as $3 at -e line 1.`

Comment: Doesn't handle `(  ( a - 0.01 ) ^ 2 *  ( a - 0.02 )  )` or at least runs for ever. Seems very slow anyway for complicated cases.

Comment: It seems super slow for some cases. Can you improve it by any chance? @bukfixart

Comment: For this one: `2 * (  3 * ( a - 0.01 ) ^ 2 * ( a - 0.02 ) / (a - 0.03) )` absolutely runs for ever @tchrist